# Connection to MySQL via Vagrant not working anymore since El Capitan

Tags: mysql, macos, ssh, vagrant

I'm using vagrant and I'm using the following config to connect to my database.

[image]

SSH Password ist the `private_key` file in the `/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/` folder. This worked without any problems, but since I've updated to El Capitan, I can't connect.

I'm getting those details

> Querious was unable to create an SSH connection because the remote host denied permission.
>
> Double-check that the SSH user name and password (or public key, if using key-based authentication) are correct.

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.7
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tzfrs/work/Server/194.6.226.31/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tzfrs/work/Server/194.6.226.31/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:2222 as 'vagrant'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:kBFNbCLWp1m4X03xMWxWeCjaQUEa426OsJ5IC/PNisM
debug1: Host '[127.0.0.1]:2222' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/tzfrs/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/tzfrs/work/Server/194.6.226.31/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 502
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

**As requestes this is the output of `vagrant ssh-config`**

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/tzfrs/work/Server/194.6.226.31/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

What do I have to do to make it work again?

Comment: can you `vagrant ssh` and can you paste output of `vagrant ssh-config`

Comment: I can connect without problems.

Comment: `ssh-config` is http://pastebin.com/9mNARCFe

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, connecting with PSequel to the Postgresql database in the Vagrant box. Two variations of the same solution:

**Vagrant key**

- Execute `vagrant ssh-config`
- You'll see a line IdentityFile containing something like `/Users/stefbastiaansen/vm/precise-pangolin/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key`
- Connect to `ssh -p 2222 -i /Users/yourusername/vm/precise-pangolin/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1` in a new terminal window
- You'll get the notice that the authenticity of the host (127.0.0.1:2222) could not be confirmed, and the question if you're sure you wanted to continue connecting. Answer yes.
- Then open PSequel (Postgres) or Sequel Pro (MySQL) and configure it for SSH tunneling.

  - Host: 127.0.0.1
  - Port: 2222
  - User: vagrant
  - Identity File: /Users/yourusername/vm/precise-pangolin/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
- Connect.

**Your own key**

- Copy your public key to the clipboard: `pbcopy < ~/id_rsa.pub`
- `ssh vagrant`
- Add your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the vagrant box
- Open up a new terminal window
- `ssh -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1`
- You'll get the notice that the authenticity of the host (127.0.0.1:2222) could not be confirmed, and the question if you're sure you wanted to continue connecting. Answer yes.
- Then open PSequel (Postgres) or Sequel Pro (MySQL) and configure it for SSH tunneling.

  - Host: 127.0.0.1
  - Port: 2222
  - User: vagrant
  - Identity File: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- Connect.

It's the confirmation step that needs to happen before you can connect via ssh.